# How do I check if a tree object is really close to another in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I have been making a survival game in unity and I have generated the trees with the below function

**The GenerateTree function**

```
void GenerateTree(int x, int y)
    {
        //define our tree

        //generate log

        int treeHeight = Random.Range(minTreeHeight, maxTreeHeight);
        for(int i = 0; i < treeHeight; i++)
        {
            PlaceTile(log, x, y + i);
        }

        //generate leaves
        PlaceTile(leaf,x,y+treeHeight);
        PlaceTile(leaf, x, y + treeHeight+1);
        PlaceTile(leaf, x, y + treeHeight+2);

        PlaceTile(leaf, x-1, y + treeHeight);
        PlaceTile(leaf, x-1, y + treeHeight+1);

        PlaceTile(leaf, x + 1, y + treeHeight);
        PlaceTile(leaf, x + 1, y + treeHeight + 1);

    }
```

**The PlaceTile function**

```
 public void PlaceTile(Sprite tileSprite, int x, int y)
    {
        GameObject newTile = new GameObject();

        float chunkCoord = (Mathf.Round(x / chunkSize) * chunkSize);
        chunkCoord /= chunkSize;
        Debug.Log(chunkCoord);
        newTile.transform.parent = worldChunks[(int)chunkCoord].transform;

        newTile.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        newTile.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = tileSprite;
        newTile.name = tileSprite.name;
        newTile.transform.position = new Vector2(x + 0.5f, y + 0.5f);

        worldTiles.Add(newTile.transform.position - (Vector3.one * 0.5f));
    }
```

[image: But I have a problem when trees spawn like that]

I believe I need to use a **if** statement to check if another log is close by, but I need help of how to do that.

Comment: where/how is `GenerateTree` called? where ever this happens check if a tree is close (e.g. within +/- 3 units left or right) to that coordinates ... if so pick another position before even calling `GenerateTree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector2.Distance(Vector2D,Vector2D)
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Distance.html

```
if(Vector2.Distance(Log1Location,Log2Location) > 10)
{
   //Spawn?!
}
```